# Units of the Scalar field theory Lagrangian density

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, dimensional-analysis

The Lagrangian (with units $J$) connects to the Lagrangian density (with units $J/m^3$) as:

$$
L=\iiint_V \mathcal{L}d^3x
$$

---

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the classical Lagrangian density of the scalar free theory (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field_theory):

$$
\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2} \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\mu  \phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2
$$

What are the units for each term?

---

Let me have a go:

I am assuming that $\phi$ has no units.

$$
\mathcal{L}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi}_\text{no units}  - \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}m^2 \phi^2}_{kg^2}
$$

Clearly, a non-sensical equation.

Comment: *I am assuming that $\phi$  has no units.* An electromagnetic field has units, so there is no reason to think that a scalar field doesn’t.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In field theory, it is assumed that action is dimensionless and so is the speed of light ($\hbar=c=1$). So, we can write everything in terms of the mass unit. From the speed of light being unitless, we get, $[L]= [T]$ and from action being unitless we get, $[M]=[L]^{-1}$. In these units, the Lagrangian density has the dimension, $[\mathcal{L}] = [M]^4$. From the mass term in the Lagrangian density, we can find the units of the field $\phi$, $$[\phi] = [M].$$ To check whether the first term is consistent we should have the dimension of the first term as $[M]^4$.
$$[\partial_\mu \phi] = \frac{[\phi]}{[x]} = \frac{[M]}{[L]} = [M]^2.$$
Remember that the partial derivative has $\partial x^\mu$ in the denominator which has the dimension of length. So, finally the dimension of the first term is $[(\partial_\mu\phi)^2] = [M]^4$, which is the correct dimension as $[\mathcal{L}] =[M]^4$.

So, there are two misconceptions in your assumptions. $\phi$ is not unitless and the form of Lagrangian density is not written in SI units, it is written in what is called natural units with $\hbar = c = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

So my take.. Your lagrangian is given in natural units, then the action should be dimensionless. The lagrangian density should be a density in spacetime for relativistic field theory, which this seems to be. Then the units of the lagrangian density should be $\sim $M$^4$, where M is mass, because in natural units, distance $\sim $M$^{-1}$. Then both terms have the correct units if $\phi\sim$ M.

You could then convert to appropriate units if you don't like natural ones.

Comment: Can you write this Lagrangian using normal units?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation, You can find the lagrangian density in normal units under... Oops sorry, this isn't the scalar field

Comment: The action should have dimension energy$\times$time, which you get by multiplying with the planck constant, which in natural units is $1$.

Comment: So if $\phi \propto M$, then the second term of $\mathcal{L}$ is $m^2 \phi^2 \propto M^4$ - okay. Can you explain why the first term is also $\propto M^4$? The way I see it, the first term is $1/2 \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi \propto M^2$, I assumed the partial derivative does not change the units.

Comment: We have unit-wise $E \sim m c^2$ meaning that in natural units $E\sim m$. Furthermore we have $\hbar c\sim $J m$ \sim 1$ in natural units, so distance is the same units as energy inverse here, which is same as mass inverse. So $\partial_\mu\sim (m^{-1})^{-1} = m$